# how to install gmpy2 error: ‘MPFR_RNDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: python, installation, gmpy

I install gmpy2 like this:

```
yum install gmp-devel
yum install mpfr-devel
yum install libmpc-devel
```

but show these errors:

```
src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘real_round’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘real_round’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘imag_round’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘underflow’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘trap_underflow’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘overflow’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘trap_overflow’

src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘inexact’

 src/gmpy_mpc.c:1294: error: ‘gmpy_context’ has no member named ‘trap_inexact’

..........


src/gmpy2.c:969: error: ‘MPFR_RNDU’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/gmpy2.c:970: error: ‘MPFR_RNDD’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/gmpy2.c:971: error: ‘MPFR_RNDA’ undeclared (first use in this function)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

what wrong?  I have install gmp,mpfr,mpc,and their devel ,,,
but still so many errors. why?

Answer (score 2):

*I'm the maintainer of gmpy2.*

`gmpy2` requires relatively recent versions of MPFR and MPC. If `setup.py` can't find the proper versions, it will display the following warning message:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
setup.py was not able to detect the required versions of MPFR
and/or MPC. gmpy2 requires MPFR version 3.1.0 or greater and
MPC version 1.0.0 or greater. To specify a directory prefix that
contains the proper versions, use the --prefix=<dir> option.

In some circumstances, the correct versions may be present and
this warning can be ignored. If you have difficulties compiling
or running gmpy2, please try compiling with the --prefix option.

It is possible to compile gmpy2 without support for MPFR and MPC
but that is not a supported configuration. Beginning with v2.1.0,
MPFR and MPC will be required.

setup.py will continue and attempt to compile gmpy2.
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you can't install the most recent versions of GMP, MPFR, and MPC, then you will need to compile your own versions of GMP, MPFR, and MPC and then instruct `setup.py` to use your versions. I normally install my copies into `/opt/local`. The following instructions assume the source is in `/opt/local/src` and you are using an administrator account with `sudo` access.

```
$ cd /opt/local/src/gmp-6.0.0
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
$ cd /opt/local/src/mfr-3.1.2
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-gmp=/opt/local
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
$ cd /opt/local/src/mpc-1.0.2
$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
$ cd /opt/local/src/gmpy2-2.0.3
$ python setup.py build_ext --prefix=/opt/local
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

If you need to distribute the `gmpy2` library across a variety of systems (for a lab or computer cluster), it is possible to compile a statically linked version. If you need those instructions, just let me know.